# Is there Auto Update procedure for developed apps using DotNet Core?

Tags: linux, .net-core

I was researching for this capability - looking for something similar that Android has (Auto Update), when you publish application to the Store, you can push it to all devices and update will happen as soon as possible (in next minutes, hours) for the devices that they have selected an option for Auto Update.

Is there similar functionality available for the apps developed on Dot Net Core - so I can push updates to the ARM devices (Linux, Windows), like Raspberry Pi, Orange Pi, or similar.

Comment: Octopus Deploy might be something to look at, but I don't seem to find it to cover the scenarion I'm looking for - 100k devices that will need to have an update option of application. https://dzone.com/articles/deploying-net-core-apps-to-a-raspberry-pi

Comment: An app store is just a trusted distribution channel. RPI and OPI are distros and have trusted distribution channels, too. It is not clear what you are asking in the non-app store/non-distro use cases because you have not described them. Some good background reading is Peter Gutmann's *[Engineering Security](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf)*.

Comment: I would just like to cover the area of updates (to the existing application that was previously deployed), in case there is a bug fix or I need to add new functionality. I would like to cover scenario where I have 100k devices (RPi or Orange Pi) and I need to update on the fly. Thanks for sugested book/link. Other wise I will have to create additional service, that will do just that (securely update, get update, check for update, etc.). Regards.

Comment: Will have a look at this as well. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-firmware-update Azure IoT Hub.